# Passing Variables between Views SwiftUI

Tags: variables, swiftui, state, global

Basic questions again:
I want to make the variable "**anytext**" visible and accessible for all future views I am going to add. In my case the variable is going to be a *String*.

1. Does the procedure change if it's a *Float*?
2. How can I save it as a *Global variable?*
3. Does the variable delete itself if I restart the app? And how do I save variables that will remain even after restarting the app?

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct Entry: View {
        
        @State var anytext: String = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            
            VStack {
                
                TextField("Enter text here", text: $anytext)
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                    .padding()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    struct Entry_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            Entry()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create & pass in an environment object at the root view of your app, or where any 'children' views may need access to `anytext`. Store `anytext` as a `@Published` property in that `ObservedObject`. That's a pointer, but there will be lots of similar questions and stuff. Here is a [HWS article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views) which may help. 1) You use `@Published` because `String`, `Float`, `Double` etc are value types. 2) Using environment objects. 3) They are not persisted, see `@AppStorage` for saving that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create & pass in an environment object at the root view of your app, or where any 'children' views may need access to `anytext`. Store `anytext` as a `@Published` property in that `ObservedObject`.

That's a pointer, but there will be lots of similar questions and stuff. Here is a [HWS article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views) which may help.

Here is an example:

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var anytext = ""
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = MyModel()

    var body: some View {
        Entry().environmentObject(model)
    }
}

struct Entry: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: MyModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter text here", text: $model.anytext)
                .padding()
                .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                .padding()

            TextDisplayer()
        }
    }
}

struct TextDisplayer: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: MyModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(model.anytext)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

All three views have `model` which they can access, to get the `anytext` property.

To answer your questions:

1. You use `@Published` because `String`, `Float`, `Double` etc are all value types.
2. Using environment objects, as shown here.
3. They are not persisted, see `@AppStorage` for saving that.

Comment: Do you write the "class" in another file or where do you write that?

Comment: @GCMeccariello Can be in another file if you would like. In Swift there is no need to import things between files, so it really doesn't matter where you put it.

Comment: Are there any more recent articles or tutorials? Something using Xcode 13 and Swift 5.7?

Comment: @thejdah There’s nothing more recent, this is realistically still the only “good way”