# Confusion with passing data to another view. SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm building this project, and I have two views: `MenuView` and `CreateBoardView`.

What I want to achieve is to be able to create a new board on the menu screen, and so that the data I'd enter (board name and description) would be shown in the new created box. But I'm really confused about how to make it.

Here's the code for my `MenuView`:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct MenuView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var AboutBoard: BoardModel
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack(spacing: 80) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                            Text("Hey,")
                                .font(Font.custom("Montserrat", size: 25))
                            
                            Text("username")
                                .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 30))
                        }
                        
                        Image("Profile")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .trailing)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 30) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("New board")
                                .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 25))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            Text("Create with your friends")
                                .font(Font.custom("Montserrat", size: 18))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: CreateBoardView()) {
                                Text("Create board")
                            }.padding(15)
                                .frame(width: 180, height: 50, alignment:.center)
                                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [(Color.init(red: 0.58, green: 0.12, blue: 0.68)), (Color.init(red: 0.58, green: 0.12, blue: 0.68))]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 20))
                                .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.28, green: 0.00, blue: 0.34, opacity: 0.2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 7)
                                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                        }
                        
                        Image("Forum")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 180, alignment: .center)
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [(Color.init(red: 0.88, green: 0.33, blue: 1.00)), (Color.init(red: 0.69, green: 0.05, blue: 1.00))]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
                    
                    HStack(spacing: 150) {
                        Text("Your boards")
                            .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 20))
                        Text("See all")
                            .font(Font.custom("Montserrat", size: 15))
                    }.padding(.top, 20)
                    
                    HStack(spacing: 30) {
                        ForEach(0..<10) {_ in 
                            Text(AboutBoard.BoardName)
                                .font(Font.custom("Montserrat", size: 20))
                            Text(AboutBoard.BoardDescription)
                                .font(Font.custom("Montserrat", size: 20))
                        }
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 210)
                        .background(
                            Image("Board-Holder")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 250, height: 210)
                        )
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(BoardModel())
    }
}

struct MenuPagePreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuView()
    }
}
```

And my `CreateBoardView`:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct CreateBoardView: View {
    
    @StateObject var BoardInfo = BoardModel()
    @State private var SetDeadline = false
    @State private var ShowMenu = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Create a new board")
                    .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 30))
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)
                    .padding(.top, 50)
                
                Text("Enter your board's name")
                    .font(Font.custom("Montserrat", size: 20))
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
                
                TextField("Board name", text: $BoardInfo.BoardName)
                    .padding(15)
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 60, alignment:.center)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(.white))
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .font(Font.custom("Montserrat", size: 20))
                    .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.28, green: 0.00, blue: 0.34, opacity: 0.2), radius: 15, x: 0, y: 7)
                    .padding(.bottom, 25)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                
                Text("Add board description")
                    .font(Font.custom("Montserrat", size: 20))
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
                
                TextField("Board description", text: $BoardInfo.BoardDescription)
                    .padding(15)
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 60, alignment:.center)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(.white))
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .font(Font.custom("Montserrat", size: 20))
                    .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.28, green: 0.00, blue: 0.34, opacity: 0.2), radius: 15, x: 0, y: 7)
                    .padding(.bottom, 25)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                
                NavigationLink(destination: MenuView()) {
                    Text("Create board")
                }
                .padding(15)
                .frame(width: 350, height: 60, alignment:.center)
                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [(Color.init(red: 0.72, green: 0.26, blue: 0.67)), (Color.init(red: 0.47, green: 0.16, blue: 0.74))]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .scaledToFill()
                .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 20))
                .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.28, green: 0.00, blue: 0.34, opacity: 0.2), radius: 15, x: 0, y: 7)
                .padding(.bottom, 25)
                .sheet(isPresented: $ShowMenu){
                            MenuView()
                        }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CreateBoardPreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CreateBoardView()
    }
}
```

I also have this `BoardModel` but I don't know if I'm even doing it right.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class BoardModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = BoardModel()

    @Published var BoardName: String = ""
    @Published var BoardDescription: String = ""
}
```

So how to make it such way so that the `CreateBoardView` would take the input and then have it stored and shown in the menu?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please study [Apple’s SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) & [Stanford’s CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/). This is talked about extensively in Apple's tutorials, but essentially, you are skipping a step. A data model is essentially a framework for what you data will contain. This is generally a struct. When you initialize it, you get one instance of your data. Your class that is an `ObservableObject` will contain an `@Published` array of your data model, and therefore stores your data for the program.

Comment: You should restart : you are making a circular reference as CreateBoardView has a navigation link to MenuView AND MenuView has a navigation link to CreateBoardView. Your model is Create and passed as environment at the same time in  MenuView. Try to simplify your views to understand what you want to do : which view open which view ? What structure will hold the model : App , main view ? Is the model an environment object or observedObject ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71539373/displaying-data-from-one-view-in-another-view/71541215#71541215